# Copy variable location last row to another sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy the last row in one sheet (at a variable location) to the last row of data (at a variable location) in another sheet. 
So far I have tried [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615786/copy-and-paste-to-the-last-row-in-a-new-worksheet) and [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448682/copy-range-until-lastrow-and-paste-in-another-worksheet). They both copied a bunch of rows instead of the exact last row in the initial spreadsheet (WWData).

```
Sub copylastrow()
Dim Last_Row1 As Long
Dim Last_Row2 As Long
Last_Row1 = WWData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Last_Row2 = WWOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
WWData.Cells(Last_Row1).Copy WWOutput.Cells(Last_Row2)
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? Note: the WWData and WWOutput will have been previously defined.

Josh

Comment: `Cells(Last_Row1).Copy` `cells` require 2 arguments: row and column. Also, qualify `Rows.Count` with the worksheet.

Comment: Try changing `WWData.Cells(Last_Row1).Copy WWOutput.Cells(Last_Row2)` to `WWData.Rows(Last_Row1).Copy WWOutput.Rows(Last_Row2)`

Comment: Both options worked great, thank you! Do either of you want to post these as an answer?

Comment: For any who stumble on this later I ended up using a combination of the two recommendations. I qualified my `Rows.Count` with the proper spreadsheet. I also replaced any `.Cells` with `.Rows`.  A big thank you to the above posters for helping with this!

Comment: I think you can also post corrected Answer giving credit to scot and findwindow, in case they are unwilling from your side. This may benefit others in future for similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

For any who stumble on this later I ended up using a combination of the two recommendations. I qualified my `Rows.Count` with the proper spreadsheet. I also replaced the `.Cells` in the last line with `.Rows`.

End code looks like this:

```
Last_Row1 = WWData.Cells(WWData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Last_Row2 = WWOutput.Cells(WWOutput.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
WWData.Rows(Last_Row1).Copy WWOutput.Rows(Last_Row2)
```

A big thank you to @ScottCraner and @findwindow